# Newly created SSL certificate will not update

Tags: ssl, certificates, certbot

I have a self-hosted website and recently my SSL certificate expired.

Tried creating a new one with the command `sudo certbot certonly -d 'example.com,*.example.com' --manual --preferred-challenges dns`. The command runs without problems producing the following errors, producing the following output:

```
Saving debug log to /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log
Requesting a certificate for example.com and *.example.com

Successfully received certificate.
Certificate is saved at: /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem
Key is saved at:         /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem
This certificate expires on 2023-05-09.
These files will be updated when the certificate renews.

NEXT STEPS:
- This certificate will not be renewed automatically. Autorenewal of --manual certificates requires the use of an authentication hook script (--manual-auth-hook) but one was not provided. To renew this certificate, repeat this same certbot command before the certificate's expiry date.

- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
If you like Certbot, please consider supporting our work by:
 * Donating to ISRG / Let's Encrypt:   https://letsencrypt.org/donate
 * Donating to EFF:                    https://eff.org/donate-le
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
```

But still, it doesn't work, when I check it with eg. https://www.sslshopper.com/, it still shows the expired certificate. I waited more than a day and it's still nothing.

Sidenote: I don't have any TXT records set up, certbot didn't ask me to set one up, like last time

Comment: `certbot didn't ask me to set one up, like last time` but the one you set up last time is still there, correct? I gather the path `/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/` is correct for whatever is using that certificate. Perhaps whatever is using that certificate needs to be restarted?

Comment: I'm so dumb. Yes, that's right, nginx had to be restarted

Comment: Back when I used to use nginx, I never had to restart it when certs were updated. But then, I didn't have to manually update the certs either. It was all done *automatically*